# Gather similar files into separate folders based on keywords in the filenames of multi-part archives

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder that contains many rar or zip files. I want put similar files (based on *part* word in *filename* if **exist**) to own folder.by default in parent folder there isn't any folder.maybe in future another part of file added to parent directory so this time it should **move** file to his own folder instead of create new folder.

For example assume the files are:

```
Visual_Studio_2015.part1.rar
Visual_Studio_2015.part2.rar
Visual_Studio_2015.part3.rar

SQL-Server-Enterprise-2016-SP1.part1.rar
SQL-Server-Enterprise-2016-SP1.part2.rar

VSCodeSetup x64 1.29.1.rar

Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2012.update.3.part1.rar
Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2012.update.3.part12.rar
```

after moving,become looks like this:

```
Parent Directory
├───Visual_Studio_2015
│   ├───Visual_Studio_2015.part1.rar
│   ├───Visual_Studio_2015.part2.rar
│   ├───Visual_Studio_2015.part3.rar
├───VSCodeSetup x64 1.29.1
│   ├───VSCodeSetup x64 1.29.1.rar
├───SQL-Server-Enterprise-2016-SP1
│   ├───SQL-Server-Enterprise-2016-SP1.part1.rar
│   ├───SQL-Server-Enterprise-2016-SP1.part2.rar
├───Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2012.update.3
│   ├───Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2012.update.3.part1.rar
│   ├───Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Ultimate.2012.update.3.part2.rar
```

i can't use any software or compiled programming language for this problem. sorry for weak English

**update**:
in powershell somthing like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | 
  Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '.part.*' } | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir
  }
```

can separating files that have **part** in filename but not work for without it, also i must mention that all filename end with .partX (X is a digit) if it is multi parted archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it would be this:

```
$parentFolder = '<THE PARENTFOLDER THAT HOLDS ALL .RAR AND .ZIP FILES>'

# Get all files inside the parent folder with extension '.rar' or '.zip'
# Because '-Filter' only accepts a single string, we need to use a 'Where-Object' clause.
# Another way would be to use the '-Include' parameter on Get-Childitem, but for that to work
# you must either also use '-Recurse' or append '\*' to the $parentfolder like this:
#  Get-ChildItem -Path "$parentFolder\*" -File -Include *.rar, *.zip
Get-ChildItem -Path $parentFolder -File | Where-Object { $_.Extension -match '\.(rar|zip)$' } | ForEach-Object {
    # create the name of the subfolder by removing the '.partX' from the basename if that exists
    $subFolder = Join-Path -Path $parentFolder -ChildPath ($_.BaseName -replace '\.part\d+', '')
    # create this subfolder if it does not already exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $subFolder -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $subFolder -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
    }
    # move the file to the subfolder
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $subFolder
}
```

Comment: The best thing about your script is preventing from overwrite, thank you 

Answer (score 2):

If all the files are in one root folder and have the naming convention you specify, then here is one way to move them into appropriate subfolders:

```
Get-Childitem -path "C:\Test" -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Name -match "^(?<folder>.*)\.part\d+|(?<folder>.*)\.rar$") {
            New-Item -Path "$($_.Directory)\$($matches.Folder)" -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$($_.Directory)\$($matches.Folder)\$($_.Name)" -Force
        }
    }
```

Change the path in `Get-Childitem` as appropriate.  Also, you can modify the paths for `New-Item` and `Move-Item` if you want them to be located somewhere else instead of as subfolders of the root directory.